# Audio does not play through javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have an issue where audio does not play and I dont know why.

I have this audio tag and buttons in this .ejs document, because I am using nodejs
and it goes like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio">
        <source id="audioSource" src="" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

    <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
    <button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button> 
    <button onclick="check()" type="button">Check Audio Status</button>

    <script src="/js/sum.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

on the bottom there I connect a JavaScript document
in the document there are a few functions for each button
the play, pause and check status
when the browser is booted up it should start playing one of the 4 mp3 files I have in my music folder
after that, it listens for when the audio is done and then picks a random number 1-4, and sets the audio source the new sound.

```
document.getElementById("audio").addEventListener("ended", myFunction);
const audio = document.getElementById("audio");
const source = document.getElementById('audioSource');

let firstTime = 0;

function check(){
   if (audio.duration > 0 && !audio.paused) {
       alert("audio is playing");
   } else {
       alert("audio is not playing");
   }
}


function myFunction() {
   const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
   source.src = `/music/sound${i}.mp3`;
   audio.play();
}

function playAudio() { 
   if (firstTime == 0){
       firstTime += 1;
       let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
       source.src = `/music/sound${i}.mp3`;
       audio.play();
   } else {
       audio.play(); 
   }
} 
function pauseAudio() { 
   audio.pause(); 
}
```

The issue is that, it doesnt play anything, and I dont know why, any help is appreciated

In theory it should go something like - browser launches, user clicks play, and it plays audio after audio, with the ability to pause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the audio source directly on the `audio` element should help. Here's a quick example.

#### The HTML:

```html
<audio id="audioSource" src=""></audio>
```

#### The JS:

```js
const audioElement = document.getElementById("audioSource");
audioElement.src = `path/to/your.mp3`
```

---

You ought to add some kind of listener to ensure that the audio *can* play, as well ([see MDN for details on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event)). Here's an extended version of the previous example, which you could use to ensure that:

```js
const audioElement = document.getElementById("audioSource");

function onCanPlay(e) {
  this.play();
}

audioElement.addEventListener("canplaythrough", onCanPlay);

audioElement.src = `path/to/your.mp3`
```

Note that it's important to set the source *after* you attach your "can play" listener.